# Trying to change macro so that when the active cell has is a number, it changes color, but when it is not, it does not

Tags: excel, vba

This is what I currently have:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Select Case True

    Case Target.HasFormula
        Target.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        
    Case Target.Value <= 0
         Target.Interior.Color = RGB(204, 232, 255)
         
    Case Target.Value > 0
         Target.Interior.Color = RGB(204, 232, 255)
         
    Case Else
        Target.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        
End Select
End Sub
```

But this also colors text etc. Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `IsNumeric` to check if the cell is a number. I'm assuming you don't want any color applied to formulas.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then Exit Sub
    If Target.HasFormula Then Exit Sub

    Select Case True
        Case Target.Value <= 0
            Target.Interior.Color = RGB(204, 232, 255)
         
        Case Target.Value > 0 ' Or Case Else
            Target.Interior.Color = RGB(204, 232, 255)
    End Select

End Sub
```